# how to pass another database in stored procedure as a parameter in java

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures

i want to pass another database to the stored procedure in java
like 
call Sel_RptDaywiseProduction(?)
how to pass DIERP database in this SP in java in callable statement
please help
thank you.

Edit: code from the comment

```
CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{call Sel_RptDaywiseProduction(?)}");
cs.setString(1, "DIERP");
ResultSet rs1 = cs.executeQuery();
while (rs1.next()) { 
  System.out.println("mat_code = "); 
}
```

Comment: You didn't specify which kind of database system you use. Usually a stored procedure is inside a database instance, so you need to create a connection to the target instance an call the stored procedure there. If you don't have the stored procedure there, you need to create it first.

Comment: i am using ms sql 2008 database....and this proc uses another database i want to pass as a parameter.....

Comment: Please edit your question if you can, so you can format the code.

Comment: CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{call Sel_RptDaywiseProduction(?)}"); 
cs.setString(1, "DIERP"); 
ResultSet rs1 = cs.executeQuery();
while (rs1.next()) { 
System.out.println("mat_code = "); 
}

Comment: @VijayMain you mean to say this stored procedure is in some database lets say XYZ which uses tables in 'DIERP' DB right ? and you want to pass this DB name (i.e. DIERP) as parameter to your procedure ? add your stored procedure contents here...

Comment: TRANPLANQTY
    LEFT OUTER JOIN DIERP..MSTMATERIALS MSTMATERIALS ON TRANPLANQTY.MAT_CODE = MSTMATERIALS.CODE 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN DIERP..MSTCOMMCASTGRADE MSTCOMMCASTGRADE ON TRANPLANQTY.GRADE = MSTCOMMCASTGRADE.CODE